# Press keys then type message in Textbox?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was wondering if Visual Basic could emulate the pressing of keys.
I was thinking of a program that did this:

When I press a button (Button1) it would start a timer (Timer1), then press the <kbd>V</kbd> key on the keyboard and then type what was entered in a textbox (Textbox1), then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. After doing that, repeating that action a second or two later, but saying what is in (Textbox2).

Could this be possible? If yes, please respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will  tell you how:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb

And use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb

For special keys.